# Como funciona o download do site mega.co.nz e como fazer em javascript

Tags: javascript

Achei legal a forma como o site [https://mega.co.nz](https://mega.co.nz/#!7JRgFJzJ!efpJGWuPhYczLexY19ex82nuwfs4sR_DG4JXddeClH4) faz o download dos arquivos.
Qual o código para executa-ló?

*Pode ser exemplos que só funcione no Chrome.*

Comment: Iago, apesar de não ser do contexto do SOpt, você pode encontrar uma referência para algo como tal nesse [link para o SOEN][1] [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994554/download-files-like-mega-co-nz

Answer (score 1):

Ele baixa partes do base64 do arquivo, depois junta e baixa o arquivo usando um blob.

Dá uma olhada nessa lib:
https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Sergio, comente por favor algo sobre essa biblioteca para a resposta ficar mais completa.